# How to capture button clicks using Sitecore Analytics (and Mongodb)

Tags: experience-analytics

I'm a beginner in Sitecore. I need to generate the data which provides how many times the user clicks a button on the webpage. The data should be stored on MongoDB database. I'm confused with where to start and how to. Suggest some references or samples to continue.

Comment: Please edit your question to include: 1) what exactly you want to achieve; 2) what you have tried so far. Also, refer to this: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. At this point, your question is considered too broad and doesn't meet the quality standards of our site.

Comment: The question has been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at existing SBOS modules: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/SitecoreSBOSLinkTracker.aspx?sc_lang=en

> This module extends the Link Manager to add a capability to set a link
>   click to trigger a Page event.

The page events end up in the Sitecore Analytics and can be used for your reporting.

Another option is to write custom code. I wrote a [blog post](https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/02/integrating-addthis-with-sitecore-goals.html) a while back about integrating AddThis with a custom goal (replace the addthis with you button and you have a possible solution).

If feasable, I would go for the SBOS module though. Will be more flexible..

> **NOTE**: The SBOS Modules, while they work, can be buggy, depending on the needs of your solution. So make sure
>   you test appropriately before deploying to a production environment.